# Mysterious current appearing on Ltspice using LT6018 opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

Do you have an idea of where the 120 mA current (going through Cact) is coming from ? I just can't understand how the LT6018 can output that much when the datasheet says it can output max 50mA. Even if it has to saturate, it should saturate at 50mA.

Note: I tested different frequencies and it seems like it  reaaaally depends on the used frequency..Also the capacitors value have an influence. Sometimes it exceeds 50mA sometimes not(and sometimes it's chaotic).

[image]
[image]

Comment: What goal you are trying to achieve with this circuit?

Comment: @G36 it's a charge amplifier circuit. It is made to drive a piezoelectric actuator (which i modelled as a capacitor with same capacitance) but in a charge amplification mode (not voltage one). It is done in order to avoid hysteresis that shows up when piezoelectric actuators are driven with voltage amplifiers. The actuator is Cact. This circuit is based on this paper : https://www.piezodrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IntroToCharge.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the datasheet says it can output max 50mA. Even if it has to saturate, it should saturate at 50mA.

No, the 50 mA is the **maximum rating** that  means, you can expect **reliable performance** when you do not exceed that 50 mA. Look further in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6018fa.pdf) and see how \$I_{SC}\$ the **short circuit current** is 90 mA or 100 mA which is larger than 50 mA!

So the opamp **can** output more that 50 mA. But that exceeds the maximum rating and that means it will have an impact on reliability. Meaning, the opamp might not last as long as it should (if you stay below 50 mA).

Also you cannot rely on every aspect of an opamp to be modelled correctly. It is also up tou the designer to make sure that the output current never exceeds 50 mA.

Regarding your circuit: You have a large capacitive load directly to ground on the opamp's output, \$C_{act}\$ and \$C_{sens}\$ in series will be just below 700 nF. Opamps generally don't like this, there has to be some series resistance. Also stability might not be guaranteed. I think you already see that in your simulation result as the behavior is weird.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a noob in electronics so i'm discovering all you just explained. Indeed, it seems like the current I_Cact is in the same range as the short circuit current but could you share some useful links about that ? (All i found was about solar panels..). Also, about the big capacitive loads : i don't have a choice. I have to use them unfortunaletly.

Comment: Can you explain more on unstability with opamps produced by big capacitive loads ? Because to me, what you said sound like coming out of nowhere. Is it due to the fact that using opamp with big  capacitors at high frequencies needs more current (i=C*dV/dt) ?

Comment: *Can you explain more on unstability with opamps produced by big capacitive loads ?* Sorry, but that isn't easily explained to a beginner. You need to learn about linear(ized) systems, poles, zeros. Then feedback loops and how those poles and zeros relate to the stability of a feedback loop. Without understanding all that you can still just do what others do and that is **not** to connect an opamp's output to ground directly with a capacitor. Look at other people's opamp circuits and do the same.